# SQL Server 2008 R2 Installation Issues + HKLM,Software/Microsoft/DivDev/vs is not there!

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

so I've been trying to install SQL Server 2008 R2 and got a pretty popular problem, I have an unupdated version of VS2008, even when i never installed it. I tried uninstalling my VS2010 and most of the 2008 stuff it came along with, and it still didn't work. Apparently, I'm supposed to go to regedit and edit the version in the path HKLM/Software/Microsoft/DivDev/vs/servicing/...etc, etc. However, I cannot find the vs part of this dirwectory. I have DivDev and VC but no VS... maybe I'm looking at the wrong place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a 64-bit version of the OS?  If so try looking in HKLM/SOFTWARE/Wow6432Node/Microsoft/DivDev/vs/servicing/...etc

Comment: You have done a good thing... I am very thankful. You deserve a good day :)

Comment: FYI, that Wow6432Node is where any 32-bit application will look for settings on a 64-bit os.